# How to disable OperatorSubstitution in a style sheet without losing syntax highlighting for local variables

Tags: formatting, stylesheet, fonts, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to define a custom style sheet that has `"OperatorSubstitution"` set to false in order to keep fonts consistent. However, whenever I disable this, I lose syntax highlighting for some local variables. As a minimal working example, see the following image:

[image]

To disable operator substitution in the second cell, I select the cell and disable it with the option inspector. Once I click apply, local variables turn blue.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a workaround?